# Uitableview horizontal as well as vertical scrolling.

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll, scrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I want horizontal as well as vertical scrolling whole table not particular cells.
Is it possible.?

Or should I implement simple view and reload again table.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to do this however the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) states...

> A table view has only one column and allows vertical scrolling only.

Answer (score 0):

you can use collection-view for the purpose